# Is there any way to automatically siphon water from something and stop at a certain amount, then restart again to keep the water at a certain level?

Tags: water

I want to draw water from a body of water automatically and cost-efficiently to a tank, and I want the water level to remain somewhat constant in that tank. Is this possible? What type of system would I have to use? 
I want to float this tank on say, a lake or a river, so that's why I do not want the tank filling up over a certain amount--I don't want the tank to submerge.

Comment: This sounds like an [engineering](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site/4536#4536) question, so it's off-topic here. I'm pretty sure that what you want can be achieved, but the engineers will probably want to know a few more details.

Comment: P.S., Google for "fill valve."

Comment: Various incarnations of this problem have been solved since classical times. Hero of Alexandria was known for either inventing or copying several to create machines.

Comment: @PM2Ring, you're right ... the engineers in the crowd DO want to know more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use a valve on the inflow tube similar to the one in your toilet tank:  a float on the end of a lever turns the flow off when it reaches the desired level.

Comment: Is there a height difference between the water source and the tank?  A picture from the OP would make this problem much easier to answer.

Comment: Zef indicates that the water level in the tank is to be below that of the source.

Comment: Great.  Now all you have to worry about is how to ensure that if the level in the floating tank gets too high (e.g., via a leaking inlet valve), how do you get rid of the excess water?

Comment: Get a bucket and bail.